# create a outlook add-in to popup an input text field form for user info

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook

I would like to develop an Outlook 2013 add-in that can be clicked and then comes up with a form that asks for user name, phone number etc.

After all the information entered that data can be appended to the end of the mail content as the signature.

I really don't know how to call the form with input text field when clicking the add-in.

Could you give me any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may treat your VSTO based add-in as a regular .Net application. For example, in the Ribbon's button Click event handler you can create a new Windows Form instance and display it for users for gathering the required information. In the same way like you do this in WinForms applications.

You may find the [Outlook Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386094.aspx) section in MSDN helpful.